# how to wrap a data table inside reactive() or observe()?

Tags: r

In the following script I have three data frames. When I run shiny app it is giving the following error message regarding the table "data3": Error in `*tmp*`$data3: Can't access reactive value 'data3' outside of reactive consumer. ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

How can I handle this error?

#Here is this script to amend:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)


   data1 <- data.table(
    Name1 = c("John", "Mary", "David", "Sarah", "Michael", "Emily", "Daniel", "Olivia", "Jacob"),
    Age1 = c(25, 32, 47, 19, 56, 28, 39, 41, 22),
    Date1 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-04-07", "2021-04-09", "2021-04- 11", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-17"))
   )


   data2 <- data.table(
    Name2 = c("John", "Mary", "David", "Sarah", "Michael", "Emily", "Daniel", "Olivia", "Jacob"),
    Age2 = c(25, 32, 47, 19, 56, 28, 39, 41, 22),
    Date2 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-04-07", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-11", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-17"))
   )

  data3 <- data.table( 
        Period = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 1),
        AL = as.numeric(0),
        FVofEL = as.numeric(0),
        EL_total = as.numeric(0)
   )


ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      title = "Panel 1",
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "Data 1",
          rHandsontableOutput("table1")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Data 2",
          rHandsontableOutput("table2")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Data 3",
          rHandsontableOutput("table3")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

data <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
        input$recalc
        data$data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
        data$data2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
        data$data3 <- as.data.frame(data3)
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$table1))
            data$data1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1)
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$table2))
            data$data2 <- hot_to_r(input$table2)
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$table3))
            data$data3 <- hot_to_r(input$table3)
    })  

geometricMean1 <- data1 %>%
    group_by(month(Date1)) %>%
    summarize(arithmetic_mean1 = mean(Age1))%>% 
    summarize(geometric_mean1 = Gmean(arithmetic_mean1))

geometricMean2 <- data2 %>%
    group_by(month(Date2)) %>%
    summarize(arithmetic_mean2 = mean(Age2))%>% 
    summarize(geometric_mean2 = Gmean(arithmetic_mean2))


PV <- geometricMean1 + geometricMean2
R <- PV /(1+0.06)
data$data3$AL <- PV - R

FV1 <- PV*(1+0.09) 
FV2<-PV*(1+0.09)/(1+0.06)
data$data3$FVofEL<- FV1 - FV2

data$data3$EL_total<- data$data3$AL+ data$data3$FVofEL


output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data1)
})

output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data2)
})

output$table3 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data3)
})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't modify directly `data$data3` as you do in :

```
PV <- geometricMean1 + geometricMean2
R <- PV /(1+0.06)

# Not inside a reactive function
# data$data3$AL <- PV - R
  
FV1 <- PV*(1+0.09) 
FV2<-PV*(1+0.09)/(1+0.06)

# Not inside a reactive function
#data$data3$FVofEL<- FV1 - FV2
#data$data3$EL_total<- data$data3$AL+ data$data3$FVofEL
```

If you comment out these lines, the App works.

If you want to recalculate a reactive value like `data$data3` you should always do it inside a reactive consumer like `Observe`,`ObserveEvent`,...:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DescTools)


data1 <- data.table(
  Name1 = c("John", "Mary", "David", "Sarah", "Michael", "Emily", "Daniel", "Olivia", "Jacob"),
  Age1 = c(25, 32, 47, 19, 56, 28, 39, 41, 22),
  Date1 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-04-07", "2021-04-09", "2021-04- 11", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-17"))
)


data2 <- data.table(
  Name2 = c("John", "Mary", "David", "Sarah", "Michael", "Emily", "Daniel", "Olivia", "Jacob"),
  Age2 = c(25, 32, 47, 19, 56, 28, 39, 41, 22),
  Date2 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-05", "2021-04-07", "2021-04-09", "2021-04-11", "2021-07-13", "2021-07-15", "2021-07-17"))
)

data3 <- data.table( 
  Period = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 1),
  AL = as.numeric(0),
  FVofEL = as.numeric(0),
  EL_total = as.numeric(0)
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      title = "Panel 1",
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          "Data 1",
          rHandsontableOutput("table1")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Data 2",
          rHandsontableOutput("table2")
        ),
        tabPanel(
          "Data 3",
          rHandsontableOutput("table3")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    input$recalc
    data$data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
    data$data2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
    data$data3 <- as.data.frame(data3)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table1,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1))
      data$data1 <- hot_to_r(input$table1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table2,{
    if (!is.null(input$table2))
      data$data2 <- hot_to_r(input$table2)
  })
  
  # observe({
  #   if (!is.null(input$table3))
  #     data$data3 <- hot_to_r(input$table3)
  # })  
  
  geometricMean1 <- reactive(data$data1 %>%
    group_by(month(Date1)) %>%
    summarize(arithmetic_mean1 = mean(Age1))%>% 
    summarize(geometric_mean1 = Gmean(arithmetic_mean1))%>% as.numeric)
  
  geometricMean2 <- reactive( data$data2 %>%
    group_by(month(Date2)) %>%
    summarize(arithmetic_mean2 = mean(Age2))%>% 
    summarize(geometric_mean2 = Gmean(arithmetic_mean2))%>% as.numeric)
  
  
  PV <- reactive({geometricMean1() + geometricMean2()})
  R <- reactive(PV() /(1+0.06))
   
  observe({ 
    data$data3$AL <- PV() - R()
    FV1 <- PV()*(1+0.09) 
    FV2 <- PV()*(1+0.09)/(1+0.06)
    data$data3$FVofEL <- FV1 - FV2
    data$data3$EL_total <- data$data3$AL+ data$data3$FVofEL})
  

  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$data1)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$data2)
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderRHandsontable({
    print(data$data3)
    rhandsontable(data$data3)
    
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: dear Waldi, I have tried the script in the way as you have instructed. However, data3 is not getting recalculated based on tables data1 and data2. Relevant columns of data3 remain empty. Please, can you help me further?

Comment: @firuz.safaev, see my update

Comment: Perfect solution in the part where I have been seeking help. Thanks, Waldi.